# Microsoft Band 2 Webtiles uknown error

Tags: microsoft-band

could someone please help me with webtiles for Band 2? Whatever Feed Webtile I create or want to import from third party, always throws "Uknown error occurred with your band". I've tried to provide download URL with mshealth-webtile:///?action=download-manifest&url= but that didn't help either. 
I would be glad for any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install a Webtile provided by another developer, you should report the problem to them.

If you are having trouble installing a Webtile that you developed, you can send the .webtile file to msbandsdk@microsoft.com and explain what platform you are trying to install it on. We'll see if we can determine what is going wrong.

Update: I looked at the Webtile and found 2 issues:

1. The "manifest.json" file was not in the root of the Webtile zip file.
2. The "name" property in the manifest.json was too long (more than 21 characters).

After correcting those 2 problems the Webtile can be installed successfully.